# How do I get all documents in a Cloud Firestore collection using Version 9 of the Modular Web SDK?

Tags: reactjs, firebase, next.js

I am trying to get all documents in a collection using version 9 of the Web SDK. But I am getting this error:

> "TypeError: querySnapshot.map is not a function"

This is the component where I get the error:

```
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import { collection, getDocs } from "firebase/firestore";
import { db } from "../../firebase";
function CurrentUser() {
  const [names, setNames] = useState([]);
  async function getMakers() {
    const querySnapshot = await getDocs(collection(db, "users"));
    querySnapshot.map((doc) => {
      setNames((doc.id = doc.data()));
    });
  }
  getMakers();
  return <div>{names.map((doc) => doc.firstName)}</div>;
}
export default CurrentUser;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`querySnapshot` is an instance of a [`QuerySnapshot`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firestore_.querysnapshot) object, not a JavaScript Array. This means it doesn't have the normal Array methods like `map()`, `some()` and `includes()`. However, it does have its own version of a [`forEach()` method](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firestore_.querysnapshot#querysnapshotforeach) that can be used to iterate over the entries in the snapshot. If you need to access methods of a normal array, you can use the snapshot's `docs` property instead (which internally calls `forEach()` to assemble an array).

To correctly fetch the documents in the array, optionally plucking the first names of each returned document, you can use any of the following strategies:

- Option 1: `useState` and `useEffect` for each user's complete data

```js
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";

// ...

const [userDataArray, setUserDataArray] = useState([]);

useEffect(() => {
  let unsubscribed = false;

  getDocs(collection(db, "users"))
    .then((querySnapshot) => {
      if (unsubscribed) return; // unsubscribed? do nothing.
      
      const newUserDataArray = querySnapshot.docs
        .map((doc) => ({ ...doc.data(), id: doc.id }));

      setUserDataArray(newUserDataArray);
    })
    .catch((err) => {
      if (unsubscribed) return; // unsubscribed? do nothing.

      // TODO: Handle errors
      console.error("Failed to retrieve data", err);
    });

  return () => unsubscribed  = true;
}, []);

return (
  <div>
    { userDataArray.map((userData) => userData.firstName) }
  </div>
);
```

- Option 2: `useState` and `useEffect` for just each user's `firstName`

```js
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";

// ...

const [firstNamesArray, setFirstNamesArray] = useState([]);

useEffect(() => {
  let unsubscribed = false;

  getDocs(collection(db, "users"))
    .then((querySnapshot) => {
      if (unsubscribed) return; // unsubscribed? do nothing.
      
      const newFirstNamesArray = querySnapshot.docs
        .map((doc) => doc.get("firstName"));

      setFirstNamesArray(newFirstNamesArray);

      // need to remove duplicates? use this instead:
      // const firstNamesSet = new Set();
      // querySnapshot
      //   .forEach((doc) => firstNamesSet.add(doc.get("firstName")));
      // 
      // setFirstNamesArray([...firstNamesSet]);
    })
    .catch((err) => {
      if (unsubscribed) return; // unsubscribed? do nothing.

      // TODO: Handle errors
      console.error("Failed to retrieve data", err);
    });

  return () => unsubscribed  = true;
}, []);

return (
  <div>
    { firstNamesArray }
  </div>
);
```

- Option 3: Make use of a tree-shakeable utility library like [`react-use`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-use) to handle intermediate states.

```js
import { useAsync } from 'react-use';

// ...

const remoteUserData = useAsync(
  () => getDocs(collection(db, "users"))
);

if (remoteUserData.loading)
  return (<div>Loading...</div>);

if (remoteUserData.error) {
  console.error("Failed to load data! ", remoteUserData.error);
  return (<div class="error">Failed to load data!</div>);
}

const userDataArray = remoteUserData.value;

return (
  <div>
    { userDataArray.map((userData) => userData.firstName) }
  </div>
);
```

Comment: "you can use the snapshot's `docs` property instead (which internally calls `forEach()` to assemble an array" I did not know that, so went to check and you're right: https://github.com/firebase/firebase-js-sdk/blob/master/packages/firestore/src/api/snapshot.ts#L409-L413  :)

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen Yeah, it's a neat little trick they do to maintain the order defined by the query and provide an Array-based interface without having to inject the Array prototype into the snapshot classes.

Comment: I've been wanting to add `map` and other list comprehension operations to Realtime Database's `DataSnapshot` too, but... time. :-/

Comment: @samthecodingma thanks so much I appreciate your quick response. I appreciate.

Answer (score 0):

```js
useEffect(() =>
    onSnapshot(collection(db, 'posts'),
      snapshot => {
        setPosts(
          snapshot.docs.map(doc => ({
            id: doc.id,
            ...doc.data()
          }))
        )
      })
    , [])
```